# How can i read out the Id with the name

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to code a little program taht should read out the id from a database. you only got the name that you type in a textbox and that it should search the id from the name and put it out.

I have tried to change the strings and the sql statement

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con1.Open();
            if (con1.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string nameInput = txtNameInput.Text;
                string query = "SELECT id " + "FROM test" + "WHERE name LIKE 
                '" + nameInput + "'";
                txtIdOutput.Text = query;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con1);
            }
        }
```

when I put in a name and press on the button, i will see the sql statement in the second textbox but not the id. i want the id

Comment: Please parametrise your queries. Your application has a huge security flaw, in that it can, and will, suffer from SQL Injection. If you don't know what that is, I **strongly** suggest reading up on it.

Comment: sorry my badddd

Comment: You see the query in the text box because you assign the query to it: `txtIdOutput.Text = query;`

Comment: You would put the result of the query, not the query itself. You need to find a tutorial on how to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: Also, since you're using LIKE, you might want to wrap the input in "%" characters.  Without them, it's looking for an exact match.

Comment: See: [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: with this query you can get more than one result because you use "LIKE" so you have to concat all the id you find.

Answer (score 2):

Not the perfect implementation, but it should get you started:

```
txtIdOutput.Text = string.Empty;

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
         command.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM test WHERE name LIKE @name";
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtNameInput.Text);

          using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
               while(reader.Read())
               {
                   txtIdOutput.Text += reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
               }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: dose not work? why you put he txtIdOutput on the top? i want that you put a name into a textbox, the database search the name and the id from the name and that it should give me the id out.

Comment: Oh wait a second I have found the error, was my bad, it nearly works the only thing that is wrong is that the id is put out by the name textbox and not the id textbox, but i try to fix it by myself

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Fixed it.